# Concatenation of two WAV files failed

Tags: java, javasound, javax.sound.sampled

I have this simple code to concatenate two wav files. Its pretty simple and the code runs without any errors. But there is a problem with the output file. The output file generated does not play, and surprisingly its size is only 44 bytes whereas my input files "a.wav" & "b.wav" are both more than 500Kb in size.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class WavConcat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wFile1 = "./sounds/a.wav";
        String wFile2 = "./sounds/b.wav";

        try {
            AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wFile1));
            AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wFile2));

            AudioInputStream appendedFiles = 
                            new AudioInputStream(
                                new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),     
                                clip1.getFormat(), 
                                clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

            AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                            AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,new File("./sounds/ab.wav"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your code, worked fine for me. please check, as @AndrewThompson suggested, format of both files. PS. 44 bytes is the length of wav header.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The original samples were simply downloaded from the Internet. They are simple mp3 sounds from "a" to "b" and "0" to "9".

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried a software called audacity(audio-editor) that did the trick. Finally it is working. Thanks a lot for all the help. I appreciate it.It wouldn't have been possible without the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `clip1.getFormat()` returns-->

```
MPEG2L3 24000.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, mono, unknown frame size, 41.666668 frames/second
```

> `clip2.getFormat()` returns-->

```
MPEG2L3 24000.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, mono, unknown frame size, 41.666668 frames/second
```

That is an odd format. I can imagine the 'unknown bits per sample' is causing a problem, but also the `MPEG2L3`, since JavaSound has no inbuilt encoder for MP3.  It seems like they are not encoded properly. Try loading them in sound editing software and save them as a type of WAV or AU that Java Sound can understand 'out of the box'. Hopefully the editing software:

1. Can understand the broken MP3, and..
2. Will write a valid WAV or AU.

If you can convert them to 8 bit mono & 8KHz during the conversion, it might reduce the `byte[]` size by a factor of 6 to 1. 8KHz is considered good enough to understand speech, and for this use you need to serve the bytes of the combined sound out to the browser - so reducing it in size is crucial.

Answer (score 2):

Try this kind of structure. This worked for me

```
List audioInputStreamList = new ArrayList();

    String wFile1 = "./sounds/a.wav";
    String wFile2 = "./sounds/b.wav";

 AudioInputStream audioInputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wFile1));
 AudioInputStream audioInputStream2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wFile2));

 audioInputStreamList.add(audioInputStream1);
 audioInputStreamList.add(audioInputStream2);

 AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream1.getFormat(); // audioInputStream2 format also same

 AudioInputStream udioInputStream = new SequenceAudioInputStream(audioFormat,audioInputStreamList);

 AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,new File("./sounds/ab.wav"));
```

**UPDATE**

check for [SequenceAudioInputStream](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SequenceAudioInputStream.java.html)

Comment: I have tried this one already. It gives the same output when trying to play the file. I mean it doesn't work. The size of the output is appropriate. Still the output file doesn't play.

Comment: The problem is not with the codec. Coz I downloaded every possible player with all codecs possible. Its definetly the output of the code. I dont think appropriate output is getting created.

Comment: What is a `SequenceAudioInputStream`?

Comment: Sorry, I have added my SequenceAudioInputStream class. Please check it and change it to way you want.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I already had SequenceAudioInputStream from the jresources.org website in my package. But is it wrong to use?

Comment: @Sura  I already had SequenceAudioInputStream from the jresources.org website in my package. But is it wrong to use?

Comment: These are open source codes, I have used these in my IVR solutions and it working fine without any issues.

Comment: @Sura  Thanks for the link.  It has been a while since I looked around the JS Resources site.

Comment: @Sura Thanks a lot for all the help. I appreciate it.It wouldn't have been possible without the help.